# How to modify, delete and add to xml that is in a dataset (visual basic)

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am making a contact book where the user must be able to add, update and delete the entries of the contact book. I am using a dataset and datagridview to display the xml file that I'm using and I got the contacts to show up, but now I need to be able to add, update (i.e. chancing the first name, last name email and phone number) and delete contacts.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataSet1.ReadXml("contactlist.xml")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "student"
    End Sub
End Class
```

and here is my xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contact>
 <student>
  <FirstName>
  John
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
  Smith
  </LastName>
  <Email>
  kooldudesmith@gmail.com
  </Email>
  <Number>
  905-453-9220
  </Number>
 </student>
 <student>
  <FirstName>
  Joanna
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
  Smith
  </LastName>
  <Email>
  joannasupermail@hotmail.com
  </Email>
  <Number>
  905-453-8767
  </Number>
 </student>
 <student>
  <FirstName>
  Jaime
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
  Smith
  </LastName>
  <Email>
  little_cat_mouse@yahoo.com
  </Email>
  <Number>
  905-432-1232
  </Number>
 </student>
 <student>
  <FirstName>
  Bill
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
  Pang
  </LastName>
  <Email>
  bill.pang7@gmail.com
  </Email>
  <Number>
  647-789-123
  </Number>
 </student>
 <student>
  <FirstName>
  William
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
  Nguyen
  </LastName>
  <Email>
  ovi8.washington@gmail.com
  </Email>
  <Number>
  647-963-6531
  </Number>
 </student>
</contact>
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Comment: Essentially, i need to find out a way to modify the xml file straight from the application. I already tried to look at questions asked by others, but I couldn't quite get those techniques to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use normal DataTable methods, to save the pattern would look like this where we set the xml header and dataset name (make sure to name the table too, in this case I named it Product)

```
Using ds As New DataSet
    ' make sure to have dt table name set
    ds.DataSetName = "Products"
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim stream As New XmlTextWriter(IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test.xml"), Encoding.UTF8)
    stream.WriteStartDocument()
    ds.WriteXml(stream)
    stream.Close()
End Using
```